# Compute 'permutation' like problem with modulo

Tags: arithmetic

Say, I have some permutation or combination formula like this,
$$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!},$$
and I want to $\bmod$ the result with some big prime ($10^9+7$ for example).

I already tried with modular operation and multiplicative inverse but failed (I don't quite understand them). Can someone give me some example in code so I can grasp the idea? (I prefer C).

Comment: I suggest you first familiarize yourself with modular arithmetic.

Comment: What is the goal? What specifically did fail? It's not clear what you are trying to do, and this is really not the place to ask for code (see our [faq]). Please clarify your question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem

Comment: The goal is how to compute (nCr) mod p, especially when n gets large. I already understand modular arithmetic but I am still not familiar with modular division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ can also be written as $$\prod^n_{i=r+1}{\frac{i}{n-i}}$$

You can rearrange the numerators so you never need to modulo divide (for each $i$ there is a $n-i'$ that divides it)

```
BigInt* res=new BigInt(1);
bool flags[r]=//all false
//flags is there to make sure we don't divide twice
for(int i=r+1;r<=n;i++)
{
    int num = i;
    for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
    {
        if(!flag[j] && num%j==0)
        {
            flag[j]=true;
            num/=j;
        }
    }
    res=multmod(res,num,prime);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what I hope. I will take the idea.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that $(a + b) \pmod{p} = ((a \pmod{p}) + (b \pmod{p})) \pmod{p}$ and $(ab) \pmod{p} = ((a\pmod{p})(b\pmod{p})\pmod{p}$. In C code, computing $a + bc \pmod{p}$ is accomplished by

> t = (b*c) % p;
>   return (a + t) % p;

Regarding inverses, when $p$ is prime and $1 \leq a \leq p-1$ there is an element $1 \leq b \leq p-1$ satisfying $ab = 1 \pmod{p}$, and so $(x/a) \pmod{p} = (xb) \pmod{p}$. To find $b$ use the extended GCD algorithm to find $b,c$ such that $ab + cp = 1$.